# Soap version mismatch in magento

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I am new to SOAP. Below code works fine in my local environment, my php version is php-5.3.3 and soap client version 1_1.
`

```
    require_once "../app/Mage.php";
    Mage::app();
    $client = new SoapClient('https://mydomain/api/soap?wsdl&type=soap');
    $session_1 = $client->__getFunctions();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($session_1);echo '</pre>';

    $session = $client->login('user', 'password');
    // If you don't need the session anymore
    $client->endSession($session);
```

`

When I try to execute this code in server(php-5.3.29 and soap client 1_1),
I am getting an error as following

```
` Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ..`
```

Then we tried the code with some changes in server as

```
require_once "../app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();
$client = new SoapClient('http://mydomain/api/soap?wsdl&type=soap', Array(
                            'location' =>   'http://mydomain/api/soap?wsdl&type=soap',
                            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
                            var_dump($client);
$session = $client->login('user', 'password');
```

I got this  error

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version in ..`

Also when we tried curl http://mydomain/api/soap?   wsdl&type=soap , it worked fine.

Can any one help on this?

Comment: The whitespace in url is a typo ? Have you check if your server can actually load the WSDL in a simple web browser ? Looks like a firewall/proxy issue, so not related to code.

Comment: Hai AFract, it was a typo.  Yes, the WSDL is loading in browser.

Comment: @ArunK hard to say what is a problem without WSDL, errors suggest a soap version is wrong, try use `SOAP_1_2`.

Comment: @Piotr, Same WDSL is working fine in local environment. I tried with SOAP_1_2 but no luck.

Comment: @AFract 
 
In my local phpinfo shows _SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"] as keep-alive but in live server, it shows close. Also in server, there is parameter _SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] which is not in my local.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is a help to you, but as there's a difference in PHP versions between the local and server environments, I thought it might help.

There's a PHP bug that was fixed in 5.3.11 that caused me to get a Version Mismatch error when trying to connect to the Royal Mail Shipping API in OpenCart.

Here's details of the bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49853

Basically, the stream_context part of the http header is being ignored, and that contains the client ID and secret.

Contained within is a workaround:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP-SOAP/' . PHP_VERSION . "\r\n" . $str_auth_header);
```

where

```
$str_auth_header = "Authorization: Bearer ". $str_token;

$arr_context = array('http' =>array('header' => $str_auth_header));

$obj_context = stream_context_create($arr_context);
```